# Optimización de código forEach

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, foreach

Estoy tratando de hacer un codigo el cual devuelva el ultimo objeto de cada elemento, conseguí lograrlo de la siguiente manera:

```
let numeros=[1232,5839,2849,38594,8383];

function unidad(numeros){
  let save=[];
  for(var i=0;i<numeros.length;i++){
    save.push(numeros[i].toString().slice(-1));
  }
  
  return save
}
```

Sin embargo devuelve lo esperado pero en string:

```
[ '2', '9', '9', '4', '3' ]
```

Habra alguna manera que de el mismo resultado pero sin pasarlo a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay una forma de hacerlo un poco más compacto, sin necesidad de transformar el número en una cadena. Para ello te apoyas en las matemáticas y el [operador de residuo o resto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder): `%`.

La idea es obtener el resto de dividir cada número entre 10, de esta forma obtendrás el último dígito de cada valor, es decir el valor de la "unidad" de cada número. Usando el método [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) puedes obtener el resultado. Por ejemplo:

```js
const numeros=[1232,5839,2849,38594,8383];

function unidad(numeros){
  return numeros.map(num => num % 10);
}

console.log(unidad(numeros));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Answer (score 4):

No veo por el momento una forma mas optima de hacerlo sin caer en más iteraciones u operaciones matematicas, asi que te dejo un pequeño hack que te dejara los numeros como tipos enteros:

```js
let numeros=[1232,5839,2849,38594,8383];

function unidad(numeros){
  let save=[];
  
  for(var i=0;i<numeros.length;i++){
    save.push(numeros[i].toString().slice(-1) | 0);
  }
  
  return save
}


console.log(unidad(numeros));
```

La clave es esta parte de aqui:

```
numeros[i].toString().slice(-1) | 0
```

Donde el operador binario `|` seria el equivalente a hacer un `parseInt` pero a nivel de bit, es decir, es una operacion un poco mas rapida, esto se conoce como pipe, y enrealidad el numero que pongas al lado derecho del pipe (`|`) no importa, puede ser cualquiera, ya que aqui el pipe se usa es para transformar el valor a entero de manera rapida pasandole al pipe un tipo entero cualquiera, aunque por convencion normalmente se usa el numero 0.

Esto te transformara cada string del array a un numero.